# Why after GroupBox control deleted from Form, the TextBox is not created on the Form?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm newer in WinForms VB NET programming.

I need to create text box at a run time.

I found the following VB NET code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim textbox1 As New TextBox
    textbox1.Name = "Textbox1"
    textbox1.Size = New Size(170, 20)
    textbox1.Location = New Point(70, 32)
    textbox1.Visible = True
    GroupBox1.Controls.Add(textbox1)  

End Sub
```

When this row **GroupBox1.Controls.Add(textbox1)** and GroupBox control  are being deleted  from Form, the TextBox isn't created on the Form after the event is fired .

Any idea why it  happens?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try calling `GroupBox1.Refresh()` after you add the textbox.

Comment: What do you mean for `GroupBox control are being deleted`? The Groupbox1 has ben removed/disposed from the Form controls collection? How many groupbox do you have on your form?

Comment: You need to add the new textbox control somewhere. You need a parent control for every control you want to add to a form/usercontrol. In your case, you just create a new textbox object, but do nothing with it, you never add it anywhere.

Comment: Because you are removing the GroupBox1 line [as _highligted_ by you], you are loosing the textBox1 control. You need to add the textBox control to some container control on the form or the Main Form itself like this - **Me.Controls.Add(textbox1)**

Comment: Angshuman,you mean must be a parent control as Joachim wrote?It seems like DOM in JavaScropt

Comment: +1 Angshuman. You must *site* the TextBox somewhere by adding it to a container (and it can be the form itself). Otherwise its just an orphaned control in memory, with nowhere to display itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A child control, like a TextBox, *must* have a parent to be visible.  You give it a parent by setting its Parent property or more commonly by adding it to the Controls collection of the parent.  So if you delete the group box then you indeed can't see the text box anymore, it won't have a parent.

Arbitrarily, add it to the form instead:

```
Me.Controls.Add(textbox1)
```